How to capture and geotag a image with Raspberry Pi 4 as a companion computer to a Pixhawk Orange Cube
All. I’m quite new to the DIY drones community and programing. I want to build a drone with a Pixhawk orange cube with Copter 4.5.1 and a computer companion Raspberry Pi 4 with its own camera module V2.
Objective:
To trigger the camera on my command from Mission Planner and Geotag the picture with the data from the Pixhawk’s GPS. I have successfully made the serial connection between the Pixhawk and Raspberry Pi. I have employed a relay module that will act as a button to trigger the RPi camera from the GPIO pin with a signal from the autopilot.
I saw a solution on a drone forum and I tried to add lines of code to obtain the desired result.
The main question is if the code below would work? If not could anybody point me in the right direction? Thank you all in advance for your attention!
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from picamera2 import Picamera2
import asyncio
import os
from datetime import datetime
import exifread
import dronekit
import time
import shutil

image_path=“/home/pi/my_captures/” #folder for iamges

#camera configuration and initialization
camera = Picamera2()
camera_config = camera.create_still_configuration(main={“size”: (1920, 1080)}, lores={“size”: (640, 480)}, display=“lores”)
camera.configure(camera_config)

#gpio pins setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#Connect to the drone and wait for GPS fix
print(“Connecting to vehicle…”)
vehicle = dronekit.connect(‘/dev/ttyAMA0’, baud=57600)
print(“Waiting for GPS fix…”)
while not vehicle.gps_0.fix_type:
  pass
print(“GPS fix obtained.”)

async def capture_photo(channel):
  filename = datetime.now().strftime(“%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.jpg”)
  temp_file = “/run/shm/{}”.format(filename) # use the ramdisk for faster I/O
  camera.start_and_capture_file(temp_file)
  return temp_file

async def get_gps_data():
  return (vehicle.location.global_frame.lat,   vehicle.location.global_frame.lon, vehicle.location.global_frame.alt)

async def geotag(temp_file, gps_data):
  latitude, longitude, altitude = gps_data
  exiftool_cmd = [‘exiftool’, ‘-GPSLatitude={}’.format(latitude), ‘-GPSLongitude={}’.format(longitude), ‘-GPSAltitude={}’.format(altitude), temp_file]

  try:
      subprocess.run(exiftool_cmd, check=True)
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
      print("Error geotagging photo: ", e)
      return False
    
  return True

GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.FALLING, callback= capture_photo, bouncetime=1000)

#main function
async def main():
  while True:
    temp_file_task = asyncio.create_task(capture_photo())
    gps_data_task = asyncio.create_task(get_gps_data())
    temp_file = await temp_file_task
    gps_data = await gps_data_task
    await geotag(temp_file, gps_data)

#execute the whole code?
try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  GPIO.cleanup()


OP asked, "[will my] code work?" Seriously??? Why don't you try it?

Hello. Since I asked the question I've got the chance to test it but came to the conclusion that it doesn't properly work. What I mean by that is : the code is connecting the Raspberry Pi to Pixhawk and takes a foto but the image is nowhere. I've tried to chance the location of the photo but to no avail. I have a feeling that this line: temp_file = “/run/shm/{}”.format(filename) is some how wrong and messing with the code. Do you have any idea how to fix this?
